# Возможно ли создать свою базу данных с помощью DataSet и работать с ней как с обычной БД?

Tags: c#, ado.net, база-данных

Создать свою базу данных с помощью DataSet, сохранить и загрузить ее - в этом проблемы нет. Но как реализовать чтение, запись и поиск не загружая ее в память полностью? Смысл в том, чтобы не пользоваться сторонними программами типа SQLserver, Access и т.д. На ХэшКоде не нашел, но если уже обсуждалось прошу направить. Желательно с примером для БД, сохраненной в бинарном формате

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А SQL Compact Edition чем не устраивает? Его можно просто подцепить к проекту как dll и работать. Насколько я слышал, SqLite тоже.

Comment: Вопрос не в том, устраивает или не устраивает, а в том, возможно или нет, и если да, то как. Если в шарпе предусмотрена возможность работать с БД в памяти, то может быть и есть возможность точно также работать с этой же БД и на жестком диске. И почему бы не использовать такую возможность? И как мне кажется, это было бы даже проще и многофункциональнее...

Comment: Нет, DataSet - это "in-memory cache of data", и этим всё сказано. В Visual Studio проект типа Database local cache основан на SQL Compact Edition, а не на чистом DataSet. Сохранить на диск и прочитать с диска DataSet можно только весь.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы использовал ORM(Nhibernate, Entity Framework например), наиболее удобный вариант. Правда придётся за прилагой тащить ещё и сторонние либы...

Comment: Значит стандартных средств на шарпе не существует, только с использованием сторонних средств (библиотек)?

Comment: ну мною замечено не было (хотя я нубьё)

Comment: А чем SQL Compact Edition - не стандартное средство?

Он входит в комплект поставки дотнета.

Answer (score -2):

Рекомендую посмотреть в сторону типизированного dataSet либо ORM..

Comment: Эти инструменты вообще не для этого. Человек хочет, чтобы DataSet заменил базу данных. А ORM (к которым, в общем-то, строго типизированный DataSet тоже относится) предназначены для взаимодействия с внешней базой данных.